# Calculating the derivative of the map $T\to T^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $E$ be a banach space and $U$ be the set of all bounded invertible linear operator on $E$ with bounded inverse.

Consider the map, $f:U\to U$ by $T\to T^{-1}$

Now we are interested in calculating the 2nd order  derivatives of this map.
For the first order derivative, I got that $D(f(T))(S)=-T^{-1}ST^{-1}=-M(S),$ where $M:BL(E)\to BL(E)$ given by, $M(S)=T^{-1}ST^{-1}$

Let, $A: BL(BL(E),BL(E))\to BL(E)$ denoted by, $A(T)=T(S)$ be the evaluation map at $S.$

So , we have, $ A(D(f(T)))=-M(S).$
Therefore by chain rule, we get,

$$D^2(f(T))(S,W)=-DM(S)(W)=T^{-1}WT^{-1}.$$

It seems I am doing something wrong. Can anyone point it out?

Edit: Calculating it simply using definition, I found that the answer will be,

$D^2(f(T))(S,W)=T^{-1}ST^{-1}WT^{-1}+T^{-1}WT^{-1}ST^{-1}$

which is correct,I guess.

Comment: How $Df(T)(S) = -S^{-1}TS^{-1}$? $Df(T) : U \to U$ isn't even linear defined like that.

Comment: Sorry,Typo! I have edited, can you look at it again?

Comment: A doesn't seem well defined, do you perhaps mean A is composition wrt S? You certainly can't evaluate T on S there's a type error there.

Comment: Well,I have edited again, Can you check now? Sorry, for a late response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Tf(T)=I$ so that using product rule* for Frechet derivatives $d(FG)(x)[H] = dF(x)[H]G(x) + F(x)dG(x)[H]$ gives
$$ 0 = Hf(T)+Tdf(T)[H]$$
(the notation $df(x)[h]$ is reserved strictly for evaluation of a Frechet derivative at $x$ with an increment $h$) i.e.
$$ df(T)[H] = -T^{-1}HT^{-1}.$$

Then applying it again gives (perhaps it is easiest to consider $H$  fixed)
$$ 0 = H df(T)[K] + K df(T)[H] + Td^2f(T)[H,K]$$
So the second derivative is
$$ d^2f(T)[H,K] = T^{-1}HT^{-1}KT^{-1} + T^{-1}KT^{-1}HT^{-1}.$$

*if your Banach space has no product you can replace $FG$ with a bilinear map $b(F,G)$ to derive a general 'product rule'.

Comment: Thanks. My bad! I understood my flaw!